# Setting up a pipeline in BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm having trouble setting up a pipeline in Bitbucket to connect my repository to DeBricked, which is an online code scanning service. Here is the YAML file which describes the integration:

```yaml
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: 'DeBricked Integration'
          script:
            - git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
            - pipe: debricked/debricked-scan:3.0.0
              variables:
                DEBRICKED_TOKEN: $DEBRICKED_TOKEN
                # BASE_DIRECTORY: "<string>" # Optional
                # DEBRICKED_EXCLUSIONS: "<string>" # Optional
```

As you can see, I have added in the statement:

```yaml
    - git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
```

(The documentation and tips I've seen elsewhere present that statement without the - prefix, however I fiddled around with the syntax and I found that the only way to get that to be valid is by inserting the - prefix.)

However, I'm still getting the fatal error:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build'
```

(I've seen other articles which propose that adding that corrective statement should fix the problem. However, this is not working for me.)

The output from the execution of the pipeline indicates that the statement is executing, it shows that it took under 1 second to execute:

[image]

However, it doesn't stop the error from occurring. The error message includes a diagnostic stating that if I add that command into my script, it will prevent the error, however I can't get it to work as advertised.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for debricked/debricked-scan:3.0.0
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build'
To add an exception for this directory, call:
    git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
```

Here is the complete execution output from the **pipe** step.

```
+ docker container run \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:ro \
   --volume=/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker:ro \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/debricked/debricked-scan:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/debricked/debricked-scan \
   --workdir=$(pwd) \
   --label=org.bitbucket.pipelines.system=true \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID="$BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME="$BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE="$BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE="$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY_FILE="$BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY_FILE" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_BRANCH="$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PARALLEL_STEP_COUNT="$BITBUCKET_PARALLEL_STEP_COUNT" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG="$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG" \
   --env=CI="$CI" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PARALLEL_STEP="$BITBUCKET_PARALLEL_STEP" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_COMMIT="$BITBUCKET_COMMIT" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR" \
   --env=PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN="$PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID="$BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL="$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" \
   --env=DOCKER_HOST="tcp://host.docker.internal:2375" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_SHARED_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes" \
   --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/debricked/debricked-scan" \
   --env=DEBRICKED_TOKEN="$DEBRICKED_TOKEN" \
   --add-host="host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" \
   debricked/debricked-scan:3.0.0
Unable to find image 'debricked/debricked-scan:3.0.0' locally
3.0.0: Pulling from debricked/debricked-scan
7264a8db6415: Pulling fs layer
8928de6d3c14: Pulling fs layer
4f4fb700ef54: Pulling fs layer
2b7ef838e455: Pulling fs layer
e173fea3cade: Pulling fs layer
fc7af08a16d5: Pulling fs layer
7fee9dc293a1: Pulling fs layer
c4f131ca463e: Pulling fs layer
ae3bb37734a1: Pulling fs layer
1d9fdbb6c760: Pulling fs layer
fc7af08a16d5: Waiting
7fee9dc293a1: Waiting
c4f131ca463e: Waiting
ae3bb37734a1: Waiting
2b7ef838e455: Waiting
e173fea3cade: Waiting
1d9fdbb6c760: Waiting
7264a8db6415: Download complete
4f4fb700ef54: Download complete
7264a8db6415: Pull complete
8928de6d3c14: Verifying Checksum
8928de6d3c14: Download complete
2b7ef838e455: Verifying Checksum
2b7ef838e455: Download complete
8928de6d3c14: Pull complete
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete
fc7af08a16d5: Verifying Checksum
fc7af08a16d5: Download complete
2b7ef838e455: Pull complete
c4f131ca463e: Verifying Checksum
c4f131ca463e: Download complete
ae3bb37734a1: Download complete
1d9fdbb6c760: Verifying Checksum
1d9fdbb6c760: Download complete
7fee9dc293a1: Download complete
e173fea3cade: Verifying Checksum
e173fea3cade: Download complete
e173fea3cade: Pull complete
fc7af08a16d5: Pull complete
7fee9dc293a1: Pull complete
c4f131ca463e: Pull complete
ae3bb37734a1: Pull complete
1d9fdbb6c760: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:604965fecd783c47bb88386c********62a4d5ef6933175be616d978ba4a68e3
Status: Downloaded newer image for debricked/debricked-scan:3.0.0
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build'
To add an exception for this directory, call:
    git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
Integration: bitbucket
Working directory: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
```

Comment: I also tried the following: git config --system --add safe.directory '*' which supposedly is a "super command" to relax checking for all users for all folders, but this didn't fix the issue. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Getting-code-128-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repository/qaq-p/2373506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the answer. Ultimately, the main problem here is poor documentation on the part of the vendor.

DeBricked hosts a sample of this pipeline within a public Bitbucket account. I can't execute the pipeline of course, but I can view the log results.

https://bitbucket.org/debricked/example-use-of-debricked-pipe/pipelines/results/21

Lo and behold, the same "fatal" error (not so fatal, evidently) is issued, yet the script continues to execute and the results are as expected upon completion!

Ultimately, there is no problem here. So, if you receive this exception with this particular integration, simply allow the script to continue; despite the exception, you should see the expected results.

[image]

Since posting this, I have been in contact with the vendor - deBricked. They now have a new pipe, v3.0.1 which does not emit the fatal error.

```
- pipe: debricked/debricked-scan:3.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this is triggered by an unadvertised update in the git version featured in the pipe and the `git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build` instruction must be done in the very pipe (e.g. in its Dockerfile), not in your pipeline step script.

This is because the instruction will alter `$HOME/.gitconfig` for the pipeline user but that is not mounted in the pipe, as you can see from the `--volume` flags in the docker run instruction.

To be clear, if you are using a public pipe from debricked, this is something that should be addressed here https://bitbucket.org/debricked/debricked-scan/src/master/Dockerfile . An immediate workaround for you would involve forking that pipe and using your fixed fork in your pipeline. To do that, just note the `pipe: namespace/pipe:version` directive refers to a tag in a bitbucket.org/namespace/pipe repository.

You could try dropping the `[--global]` flag and see if this moves the config value into `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.git/config`, which is indeed mounted into the pipe, and is still honored.

Comment: I tried this suggestion but it did not fix the problem. When you say the instruction must be done in the pipe, does that mean that this is something which DeBricked must remediate? Or is there something I can do at my end? This is the first time I'm ssetting up a pipeline. I'm just following tutorial instructions and I don't know anything about the technical aspect of what I'm doing. But if there is something I can do to remediate this, I'm happy to get off the documented path and give it a try.

Comment: updated answer to clarify that!